# Setup new connection in mysql workbench using standard TCP IP over SSH

Tags: 20.04, permissions, ssh, connection, mysql-workbench

Could not read the contents of .ssh directory
Error opening directory '/home/[username]/.ssh': Permission denied

I can see in the list of running processes that mysql-workbench is not running as root user.

I am not sure what the actual issue is. I only want to load '/home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa' file while adding parameter in 'SSH key file' during connection setup. So that my connection should be established successfully.

Comment: I am bit new to Ubuntu operating system. Any sort of help will be a great favor...

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it? Also what you added as a comment should have been added to the question as an edit.

Comment: Hi @David, you are write. I will improve & adapt this questioning mechanism. I am using Ubuntu `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was to copy the SSH private you need key in question from that .ssh folder.
Just put it in some new folder, use that copy of the key, and it should work.